# How to get bash alias expanded in python script

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, alias

Need to get bash aliases expanded in python script. Tried many ways to get the value readed but could'nt get it.

1. check the command if its a bash alias return the expanded form
2. If the command is not bash alias return the command itself.

Shell script it can be achieved by :

```
alias testalias='aliascommand'
cmd="testalias"
shopt -s expand_aliases
newcmd=${BASH_ALIASES[$cmd]}
echo "$newcmd"
```

Comment: Short answer is "you can't" (or at least "you shouldn't"). Aliases are an interactive-extension-annex feature that versions of bash compiled to be noninteractive-only aren't guaranteed to support at all, and moreover they're process-local; there's no persistent storage between your interactive shell, your Python interpreter, and a noninteractive shell the Python interpreter starts with `subprocess` (which is where you'd need them to be interpreted). And aliases are turned off by default in noninteractive shells in the first place.

Comment: There are some _very_ ugly hacks you could do, but as I said, they're horrible awful ugly hacks that nobody should ever do (think "make your scripts break when you change your interactive shell's configuration" level awful). A much better practice would be to use _exported functions_ instead of aliases; then you just need to tell `subprocess` to use bash instead of sh and everything will Just Work.

Comment: (aforementioned ugly hacks universally involve instructing your noninteractive shell to source configuration files meant for interactive shells only).

Comment: BTW, you can see the history of the bash IRC channel's alias factoid at http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/alias. You'll note that for pretty much all of its history, the advice has been some variant on "if you have to ask, use a function instead".

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with help from the shell **before** you start Python:

```bash
for alias_name in "${!BASH_ALIASES[@]}"; do
  printf -v "alias__${alias_name}" %s "${BASH_ALIASES[$alias_name]}" \
  && export "alias__${alias_name}"
done
```

...after which `os.environ.get(f'alias__{name}', None)` will return any alias that exists, so you can prepend that text to a shell command you intend to run to get the same behavior the alias itself would have.

---

For the general case, however, you should use exported functions rather than aliases; using `subprocess.Popen('...script goes here...', shell=True, executable=shutil.which('bash'))` will ensure that the script in question is executed with bash, so any functions exported by a copy of bash running in a parent process will be accessible.